# How can i exit a loop when the end of a file is reached? (java)

Tags: java

I have a program in Java that will print the contents of a text file to console. 
I created the following loop to do this:

```
if ("1".equals(select)) {
    while (true){
        System.out.println(inFile.nextLine());
    }
}
```

However I cannot edit the file itself to add a kind of character to tell me when the file end has been reached; instead the end of the file will be when I get 2 blank lines in a row, but I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: `while (inFile.hasNextLine())` perhaps? (I'm guessing `inFile` is a `Scanner` here)

Answer (score 0):

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt")))
    {

        String sCurrentLine;

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Hope this answers